# Explain GUID logic in Shell_NotifyIcon

Tags: c++, winapi

Please take a look at the following code. If I keep GUID

> { 0x781158ff, 0x21dd, 0x4aed,{ 0xb0, 0xc4, 0x6a, 0x75, 0xd7, 0x39,
> 0xc1, 0x**67** } }

then notifications arrive when the app. starts, and when an user sendS `NIM_MODIFY` at runtime.

But, if I change GUID to

> { 0x781158ff, 0x21dd, 0x4aed,{ 0xb0, 0xc4, 0x6a, 0x75, 0xd7, 0x39,
> 0xc1, 0x**66** } }

then icon is not present in the tray.
Logs are that `::Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &m_notification_data)` produces `Unknown error`, and `::Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &m_notification_data)` produces `Unknown error` as well.
I know that this GUID (with 0x**66** at the end) is used in another app. in the system.
Please explain how logic related to GUID works when I call `Shell_NotifyIcon`.

Code is below.

```
ShellIcon notificMonWnd(NULL, LOG_PATH);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    strcpy_s(szWindowClass, MYWNDCLASS);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, SW_HIDE))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // ... more code
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   // Initialize menu
   hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_ADD_TO_AUTORUN_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "Add to Autorun");
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_REMOVE_FROM_AUTORUN_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "Remove from Autorun");
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_OPEN_LOG_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "Open log");
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_MODIFY_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "Modify icon's data");
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_ABOUT_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "About");
   AppendMenuA(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_EXIT_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, "Exit");

   // Add icon to tray.
   notificMonWnd.notify(NIM_ADD, TRAY_ICON_MESSAGE, hWnd, IDI_EXCLAMATION);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            // ... more code
            case ID_TRAY_MODIFY_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM:
                OnModifyIcon(hWnd);
                break;
            // ... more code                
            }
        }
        break;
        // ... more code
    }
}

void OnModifyIcon(HWND hwnd)
{
    Log::append(LOG_PATH, "OnModify", "entered");
    notificMonWnd.notify(NIM_MODIFY, TRAY_ICON_MESSAGE, hwnd, IDI_EXCLAMATION);
    Log::append(LOG_PATH, "OnModify", "exited");
}

 bool ShellIcon::notify(unsigned int dwMessage, UINT uCallbackMessage, HWND hwnd, LPSTR iconId)
{
    Log::append(m_log_path, "notify", "entered");

    ZeroMemory(&m_notification_data, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
    m_notification_data.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);

    BOOL r = ::Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &m_notification_data); // delete old balloon message
    if (r == FALSE)
    {
        std::string msg;
        utils::getLastErrorMessage(msg);
        Log::append(m_log_path, "notify,NIM_DELETE", msg);
    }

    // N.B.!!! Displays balloon notification
    m_notification_data.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_INFO;
    if (utils::isWin7OrLater())
    {
        m_notification_data.uFlags |= NIF_GUID;
        // N.B.!!! GUID differs from GUID used in earlier call to Shell_NotifyIcon in onCreate.
        // If you set the last value to 0x66 you'll never see the icon.
        m_notification_data.guidItem = { 0x781158ff, 0x21dd, 0x4aed,{ 0xb0, 0xc4, 0x6a, 0x75, 0xd7, 0x39, 0xc1, 0x67 } };
    }
    else
    {
        m_notification_data.uID = 1; // superfluous as guidItem was set
    }

    // Set szInfo field.
    m_notification_data.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO; // info notification
    ::LoadString(m_module_instance, IDS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, m_notification_data.szInfoTitle, sizeof(m_notification_data.szTip) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    ::LoadString(m_module_instance, IDS_DEFAULT_TIP_MESSAGE, m_notification_data.szInfo, sizeof(m_notification_data.szInfo) / sizeof(TCHAR));

    // Set szTip field.
    TCHAR notificationMessage[128] = { '\0' };
    // concatenate <title> - <tool tip message>
    ::LoadString(m_module_instance, IDS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, m_notification_data.szTip, sizeof(m_notification_data.szTip) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    ::LoadString(m_module_instance, IDS_DEFAULT_TIP, notificationMessage, sizeof(notificationMessage) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    strcat_s(m_notification_data.szTip, _T(" - "));
    strcat_s(m_notification_data.szTip, notificationMessage);

    // Set icon.
    m_notification_data.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(m_module_instance, iconId);
    if (m_notification_data.hIcon == NULL)
    {
        std::string msg;
        utils::getLastErrorMessage(msg);
        Log::append(m_log_path, "notify,LoadIcon", msg);
    }

    // Please leave here code that may differ from original 
    // implementation of NotificationWindowMonitor::Notify
    m_notification_data.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
    m_notification_data.uCallbackMessage = uCallbackMessage;
    m_notification_data.hWnd = hwnd;

    r = ::Shell_NotifyIcon(dwMessage, &m_notification_data);
    if (r == FALSE)
    {
        std::string msg;
        utils::getLastErrorMessage(msg);
        Log::append(m_log_path, "notify,Shell_NotifyIcon", msg);
    }
    
    Log::append(m_log_path, "notify", "exited");

    return r;
}
```

Comment: You received links to the documentation when you asked the same question previously. In deleting that previous question you also purged all the information that was submitted there. That's unhelpful, and fairly rude.

Comment: @IInspectable, in docs it is said that The path of the binary file is included in the registration of the icon's GUID and cannot be changed. How do you interpret this sentence? What function do I call to register the icon's GUID?
Between, I did not move the binary file.

Comment: The documentation talks about *accidental* attempts to re-register GUIDs for notification area icons. A common error mode in this case would be, if the application that registered a GUID was moved. The documentation doesn't describe the scenarios under which a premeditated attempt to hijack GUIDs can fail. It is left as an exercise to the malevolent player to extrapolate the documented error scenarios.

Comment: @IInspectable, so when I used that GUID with 0x66 at the end it was interpreted as an attempt to hijack this GUID by my application. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Well, where did you get that GUID from? If you got it through, say, guidgen.exe, then you are in the camp of developers, that need to fix an issue as a result of an accident, and the documentation applies, as written. If you got the GUID by inspecting other code and/or assets, then you are in the camp of developers that try to fight the system. In that case, you're going to have to translate the documentation to match the expectations of an attacker. The primary audience for the documentation isn't attackers.

Comment: @IInspectable, I found the latest GUID used in my app. here `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2983138283-4284210046-3001952672-1001\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify\ToastAppIdentities\Microsoft.Explorer.Notification.{781158FF-21DD-4AED-B0C4-6A75D739C161}`
Any ideas what it means?

Comment: In all honesty, I have never had any good luck using the GUID feature of `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, it causes more problems than it tries to solve. So I just stick with the old `HWND+ID` way instead and it works just fine.

Comment: @alexander.sivak *"I know that this GUID (with 0x66 at the end) is used in another app."* How do you know this `GUID` identifies a icon instead of other recources? And except the `GUID` itself, [the path of the binary file that contains the icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa#troubleshooting) also may play a role in the failure of `Shell_NotifyIcon` call.